# Dictionary object has no attribute split

Tags: python, dictionary, split

My data file looks like this:

```
{'data': 'xyz', 'code': '<:c:605445>  **[Code](https://traindata/35.6547,56475', 'time': '2021-12-30T09:56:53.547', 'value': 'True', 'stats': '96/23', 'dupe_id': 'S<:c-74.18'}
```

I'm trying to print this line:

```
35.6547,56475
```

Here is my code:

```
data = "above mentioned data"
for s in data.values():
    print(s)
while data != "stop":
        if data == "quit":
            os.system("disconnect")
        else:
            x, y = s.split(',', 1)
```

The output is:

```
{'data': 'xyz', 'code': '<:c:605445>  **[Code](https://traindata/35.6547,56475', 'time': '2021-12-30T09:56:53.547', 'value': 'True', 'stats': '95/23', 'dupe_id': 'S<:c-74.18'}
x, y = s.split(',', 1)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I've tried converting it into tuple, list but I'm getting the same error. The input in x,y should be the above mentioned expected output (35.6547,56475).
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
x,y = d['code'].split('/')[-1].split(',')
```

That means, you need to access the dictionary by one of it's keys, here you want to go for 'code'. You retrieve the string '<:c:605445>  **[Code](https://traindata/35.6547,56475' which you can now either parse via regex or you just do a split at the '/' and take the last element of it using [-1]. Then you can just split the remaining numbers, that you are actually looking for and write them to x and y respectively.

Of course, you might want to check your incoming data to be valid by catching the KeyError you mentioned in the comments:

```
try:
  x,y = d['code'].split('/')[-1].split(',')
except KeyError:
  print(f'Data invalid. Key "code" not found. Got: {data} instead')
```

Comment: I tried running it and I'm getting a KeyError: 'code'

Comment: @Dustrokes I've taken your reference dictionary which clearly has a key 'code' in it: {'data': 'xyz', 'code': '<:c:605445>  **[Code](https://traindata/35.6547,56475', 'time': '2021-12-30T09:56:53.547', 'value': 'True', 'stats': '95/23', 'dupe_id': 'S<:c-74.18'}

Comment: @Dustrokes You code needs to parse the incoming data differently. You are looking for a string ("stop", "quit") as a breakout/termination condition on the one hand and by accessing a dictionary on the other. You need to get your input data sources more coherent. And may be error handling would be another good idea. ;)

Comment: I did try that, I tried printing the output and edit a few lines and it worked, I can see the data now !! Thank you so much for the explanation :D

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a simple regex on the code element - regex starting at the end of the string, find all digits to a . find all digits to a , find all digits.

```
import re

d = {'data': 'xyz', 'code': ':c:  **[Code](https://traindata/35.6547,56475', 'time': '2021-12-30T09:56:53.547', 'value': 'True', 'stats': '96/23', 'dupe_id': 'S<:c-74.18'}

print(re.findall(r'\d+.\d+,\d+$', d['code'])[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can only split text not a dictionary type
first get the text that you want to split

`d['code']`